# Etymology of "Horsengoggle"

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms

(Note to the dyslexic: be sure NOT to confuse this with “Google”.)

Horse and goggle --> Horse 'n' goggle --> Horsengoggle

There is a Wikipedia entry for this hand game: a kind of *rock-paper-scissors*, or *drawing straws* for a group to pick a single 'winner'.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsengoggle
- http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=horsengoggle

My question is, within the context of this game, **where did the name come from?**

My best guesses:

- A jockey on a horse who wears goggles running around a track like the circle of people?
- The goggles that a horse wears, like blinders?
- People goggling (gaping) at a horse race?
- Horsing around and goggling the results?
- Somehow related to the dice, poker, and basketball games called “horse”?
- ?

The game may have started in Germany, or from an American whose family came from Germany, so maybe “goggle” has some alternate meaning lost in translation?

Comment: I'm familiar with the word [hornswoggle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hornswoggle), which means to defraud/cheat someone by means of deceit and figurative slight-of-hand.

Comment: The quotation from Jim Frank in the Wikipedia piece suggests a German origin. And there is a village named Gagel roughly halfway between Berlin and Hamburg. *Die Gage* is a fee or salary, of which *Gagel* could be a diminutive. But I cannot come up with a German word that could even be corrupted into Horsen.

Comment: I'd guess that's describing the consecutive actions in the game.  First you *horse* which somehow means to throw your chosen fingers into the circle and then you "*goggle*" (look at) the total.  But I've got nothing to support that.

Comment: Perhaps,it's got something to do with people goggling at horses to place their bets before a race? I'm guessing here.

Comment: Very few information on the net, nothing about the origin. I couldn't find anything in German sources also. Probably, someone just made up a nonce word and people adopted it.

Comment: @ hotlicks, thanks - I was suddenly terrified I'd gotten hornswoggled wrong all my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ***horsen*** is an archaic term meaning “horses”

> From Middle English *horsen*, alternative plural of *hors*, equivalent to horse +‎ -en ‎(plural suffix). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horsen)

The term ***gog*** (noun) is an obsolete term, which means [haste; ardent desire to go](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gog), and M&W define it as *[stir, excitement, eagerness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gog)*.

The suffix ***-le***:

> From Middle English *-el*, from Old English *-el*, *-ol*, *-ul* ‎(agent suffix), from Proto-Germanic * *-ilaz* (agent suffix). Cognate with West Frisian *-el*, Dutch *-el*, Low German *-el*, German *-el*.
>   ‘A suffix forming agent nouns from verbs’:

Intuitive Guess:  ***horsengoggle*** could mean: “horses who can't wait to begin/start/go”

Comment: If it has a German origin, this is unlikely as German for horse is *Pferd*. It might relate to German *Hosen* meaning trousers/pants. It doesn't seem to be old enough to have a Middle English origin.

Answer (score -3):

My guess is that it is a nonsense word and it's origin has no meaning other than thought adequately silly by it's inventor.